# running a class at each 1 second is not work as expected

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Timer() in the main activity. But, somehow it is not working as I expect. I will show key code section to you.
ERROR : 
         icon is not changed

```
public class X extends Activity {
       private Timer timer = new Timer () ;
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       public void onCreate(Bundle a) {
              //..
              timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Device(),  1000, 1000  );

       }
```

}

```
public class Device extends TimerTask {
       Image e;
       View w;
       public void run() {
           e = ( ImageView ) w.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
           if ( isVolited ( ))
                   e.setBackground(w.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1));
               else
                   e.setBackground(w.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2));
```

LOG :

```
 01-29 14:25:51.175: E/TabletStatusBar(2172): closing mini mode apps panel
 01-29 14:25:51.255: E/TabletStatusBar(2172): closing mini mode apps panel
 01-29 14:25:56.510: E/lights(2051): write_int failed to open /sys/class/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness
 01-29 14:25:59.105: E/lights(2051): write_int failed to open /sys/class/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness
 01-29 14:26:00.060: E/TODmobile(3509): onReceive action=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
 01-29 14:26:00.060: E/TODmobile(3509): hour : 14    minute : 26
 01-29 14:26:00.060: E/DigitalClockWidget(3509): updateWidgets
 01-29 14:26:00.065: E/TODmobile(3509): hour : 14    minute : 26
 01-29 14:26:10.725: E/Watchdog(2051): !@Sync 504
```

Comment: please post the log and the code of isVolited().

Comment: @StefanBe isVolited() is just return true if it is called second time, it returns false ... .

Comment: yes I am interested in how you do that :)

Comment: Per Stefans Comment are you absolutely sure that the else condition is being executed. From a LOG STMT, Debugger

Comment: @SeanMcCully YEs, I have changed icon1 as icon2. but result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it is working

```
Timer time = new Timer();
TimerTask doThis;

int delay = 1000; // delay for 5 sec.
int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.
doThis = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {

        e = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                e.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            }

        });

    }
};
time.scheduleAtFixedRate(doThis, delay, period);
```

Comment: Where should I put the `doThis = new TimerTask` ? In main class which is X or other one ?

Comment: John I feel you are trying to help me. For this reason, I donot want to bother you but interestingly `e in the run method returns nullException`

Comment: Should I put layout related to the view ?

Comment: Error: `(11475): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: I have put all your answer on the onCreate method of the main.

Comment: Noooooooooooooow, it is worked. ( Thank you [comes from my heart]) * 100000000...000

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update the UI thread from a worker thread. You have to use handlers or Aysn Task to update the UI thread.

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                               e.setBackground(w.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1));


                    }
                });
```

Comment: How can I call the run function at every 1 second?

Comment: Put this code inside your run() method of the class. Run()-->handler--->run()

Comment: Error: handler is not defined. What should I do ?

Comment: Handler handler = new Handler(getApplicationContext());